# Restricting memory regions to threads

Tags: linux, multithreading, memory, memory-management, virtual-memory

Is there an operating system-specific way in Linux/Darwin/Windows, to restrict access to certain virtual memory pages to only one thread, so that when another thread tries to access it, the OS would intercept and report an error?

I'm trying to emulate the behavior of `fork` with multiple processes, where each process has its own memory except for some shared memory, mainly to avoid all programming errors where one worker would access memory belonging to another worker.

Comment: Then turn your problem around, use fork() but set up some shared memory segments first.

Answer (score 0):

As a general proposition, this is not possible. The whole idea of threads is to have multiple streams of execution that share the same address. If you're a kernel mode kommando, you might be able to some up with some modification of the page tables that a thread uses to make pages inaccessible from usermode then unlocks them.